# Did not get passport stamped in Oman to UAE

Tags: visa, passport, uae

I am in Dubai on a tourist visa and had to exit the UAE to Oman for a visa change. I got a job in Dubai and had to get my Employment Visa stamped. So I went from Dubai to Oman to "exit". However, in Oman, I somehow found myself at the airport gate for my flight, possibly not getting to the stamp section. So I didn't get my passport stamped. I only knew that I had to get my passport stamped when I asked the other passengers who were also exiting. When I went back to Dubai, the immigration office still stamped my Employment Visa. I'm not sure if the Oman stamps were required or he didn't notice them. Or the only thing he needed to see was the Dubai exit stamp.

Will I be in trouble for this? Will my Employment Visa be completed or are the Oman entry/exit stamps required when processing my visa change?

Comment: From my experience (I worked in UAE for 6 months back in 2010 and had to do the Oman visa run every so often) you have to have the exit/re-entry stamps in your passport. That is how UAE immigration sees that you actually have left the country. On another hand I was able to get an extension to my visa once or twice without actually leaving the country, so maybe that is an option you can ask about.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing they check when re-entering is that you're valid to enter.  An American, for example, coming from any other country, gets a 30-day visitors visa (used to be 90 days!).  No matter how long you were absent from UAE.  Other countries have other stipulations, but in general, you are entering the way you entered the first time: fresh.